# How to resolve the LD_LIBRARY_PATH problem in Code::Blocks using Linux

Tags: linux, codeblocks

I am running code::blocks on antix Linux (Debian 12 bookworm). When I run a simple Hello World program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

already tested and working manually in console, I got the following output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L"-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/main.o   
Output file is bin/Debug/test with size 30.12 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
 

-------------- Run: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /home/Jackie/Documents/test/bin/Debug/test
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Executing: xterm -T test -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:.:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /home/Jackie/Documents/test/bin/Debug/test  (in /home/Jackie/Documents/test/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I have tried two workarounds suggested a long time ago on the codeblocks forum:
https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,12688.new.html#new
https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,9197.msg74121.html#msg74121 (second to last post)

I have the feeling that this is actually not too hard to figure out, but I am out of ideas...

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: it does not execute the program. It exits with "Process terminated with status -1".  Does not print my "hello world" string anywhere.

Comment: then please update your question with this information (it's still much too little information to actually help you with your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. AntiX Linux is using the **ROXterm** terminal. Or maybe the name was changed from xterm to ROXterm? Anyway, adding `rox` at the beginning of the line in codeblocks Settings -> Evironment -> Terminal to launch console programs
did the trick.

```
xterm -T $TITLE -e     ---->      roxterm -T $TITLE -e
```